# How to insert nested json into SQLite Flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, sqlite, nested

I want to make a categories screen, the backend returns a nested json with 4 trees in total if I'm not mistaken,

example:

[image]

when I press the most general tree of the categories, I would like it to be displayed as a dropdown and there, put the children of this category, the ones that come in the json clearly, hope to explain myself well.

I have to fill these widgets, their text or titles with the text that comes clearly in the json, but I'm not going to be calling the endpoint every time I want to paint the titles, i have to save what comes in the json in the sqlite, and then extract from there the texts to put on categories screen ... how can I do this? I'm new, never build a structure like that, I have to do it with sqlite, but I wouldn't know how to start or how to build the tables, if I make a table, only the first tree of the categories will go, and the rest? the children of the nested json? Could someone guide me?

I leave you a piece of the json (for other reasons I can not put it complete) to put them a little more in context

```
{
    "res": 0,
    "categorias": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Bolsas",
            "img": "hogar.png",
            "titulo": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 11,
                    "name": "Para llevar",
                    "img": "llevar.png",
                    "titulo": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Para Conservar",
                    "img": "consrvar.png",
                    "titulo": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "Para Organizar",
                    "img": "organizar.png",
                    "titulo": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "Multipack",
                    "img": "multipack.png",
                    "titulo": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Cuidado del aire",
            "img": "aire.png",
            "titulo": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 21,
                    "name": "Instantaneo",
                    "img": "instantaneo.png",
                    "titulo": 0,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 211,
                            "name": "Aerosol",
                            "img": "llevar.png",
                            "titulo": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 212,
                            "name": "Toque",
                            "img": "consrvar.png",
                            "titulo": 0
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @ArtemViter What we did was save the entire json as a string in a table that is called only once when starting the app, when clicking the last level of categories send WHAT category, sub, etc, was clicked and the server does the work of filter and bring products based on the category we send, then when I get to the products page I already have the response from the server with a json with all the filtered products.

Comment: Is this approach similar to my answer in paragraph 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

You have several option to work with json and sqlite:

1. Just put your json as string in row on table and then select as string and convert to json.
2. You can use similar approach from paragraph 1 bud with using [sqlite's json extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html). It adds possibility to select of update parts of json by special query syntax. To use sqlite with this extension u will need custom build of sqlite like [sqlite-android](https://github.com/requery/sqlite-android) (with have many other benefits).
3. You can crate separate sqlite table from each level fo json nesting (depends on your need of granularity). For example you can create table `categorias` with columsn(categorias_id, categorias_name, categorias_img, categorias_titulo), table `categorias_childrens` with columns(categorias_id, id, name, img, titulo, categorias_childrens_id).
   In this case all rows of `categorias_childrens` table related with categorias.categorias_id contains categorias.categorias_id in categorias_childrens.categorias_id column. And all rows related with some of `categorias_childrens` row contains categorias_childrens.categorias_id in  categorias_childrens.categorias_childrens_id column (situation when children.id.21 has childrens ).

Or u can combine approaches fro example: create table `categorias` with columsn(categorias_id, categorias_name, categorias_img, categorias_titulo, children) where column children will be contains string json value.